# Get Length and Keys of JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JavaScript object like:

```
myobj: "[
        {"id":"2027","street":"street name one"},
        {"id":"2515","street":"street name two"}
       ]"
```

How can I get the length and the list of keys in this object?

I've tried:

```
var keys = Object.keys(myobj).length;
console.log(keys);
```

but it always returns a length of "1"...why?

Comment: It looks like `myobj` is a string containing JSON. You have to parse that value first.

Comment: yes it was so. i resolved with eval('var obj='+myobj);

Comment: You should use `JSON.parse` instead.

Comment: JSON.parse(myobj); ?

Comment: Yep: [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196)

Comment: good! thanks i'll read it later! :)

Answer (score 2):

`myobj` looks like it's an Array with 2 elements, which both have 2 properties. If you want the number of properties of `myobj[0]` use:

```
var myobj = [
    { "id": "2027", "street": "street name one" },
    { "id": "2515", "street": "street name two", "foo": "bar" }
];
console.log(Object.keys(myobj[0]).length); // 2
console.log(Object.keys(myobj[1]).length); // 3
```

`Object.keys` on an Array will return the same value as it's `.length` property.

```
Object.keys([ "foo", "bar", "baz"]); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved using eval.

```
eval('var obj='+myobj);
```

to get the lenght i do:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj).length;
console.log(keys);
```

to loop through elements:

```
for (i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
console.log(obj[i].id);
console.log(obj[i].street);
};
```

Comment: FYI, if you simply want to iterate over the elements in the array, you don't need `Object.keys` at all. Just do `for (var i = 0; obj.length; i++)`. `obj` is actually an array.